# Application.Evaluate Runtime Error Type Mismatch

Tags: excel, vba, type-conversion, runtime-error, runtimeexception

I am experiencing this runtime error - type mismatch on the following function call in VBA

```
Dim sTest As String
sTest = "=Search(" & Chr(34) & "MyString" & Chr(34) & Chr(44) & "A2" & ")>0"
''the above evaluates to =Search("MyString",A2)>0
Application.Evaluate(sTest)
```

So the evaluate function throws a runtime error-type mismatch

I tried

```
sTest = "=Search(" & Chr(34) & "MyString" & Chr(34) & Chr(44) & Chr(34) "Test MyString" & Chr(34) ")>0"
```

Still the same error

When I use the above string in the excel formula bar, it works!!

I tried

```
sTest = "=Search(""MyString"", ""Test MyString"")>0"
```

> It Worked in VBA

To My Surprise

```
sTest = "=Search(" & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & "MyString" & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & Chr(44) & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & "Test MyString" & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & ")>0"
```

> Din work

Could somebody help here why the first block of code does not work?

Comment: `Search` returns `#VALUE!` if nothing found, so, you can't use `Search()>0`. Use this one instead :`sTest = "=ISNUMBER(Search(" & Chr(34) & "MyString" & Chr(34) & Chr(44) & "A2" & "))"` and as Tim suggest, it's more readable to use `"=ISNUMBER(Search(""MyString"",A2))"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to include a quote in a string all you need to do is double it up:

```
sTest = "=Search(""MyString"",A2)>0"
```

to me that's easier than using `Chr(34)`

Note that SEARCH() returns an error if the string was not found, not 0.

Comment: Damn..for my manual tests I din test the error condition. Now I set the breakpoint and change the cell value in A2 to "Test MyString" and it worked. So indeed the evaluate was failing due to error returned by search. Thank you Sir.